# How to allow users to alter views returned by a controller in orchard

Tags: controller, view, orchardcms, alter

I built a custom module that returns a view based on the name of the Tenant Site (returns a different view for each tenant). Is there a way to allow users to edit the contents of this view using Orchard instead of having to go into the code and change the .cshtml file? Thank you.

Comment: Edit what exactly, and alter it in what way?

Comment: Bertrand Le Roy, I have a view that gets returned by the controller but I need the content of that view (any text/pictures such as a message) to be editable by a site admin. Another way of accomplishing this would be to somehow include a content item within the view if this is possible? Basically I just need a way for the content of my view to be editable by any site admins.

Comment: If it's content, why is it returned by a custom controller? Why not just alternate the templates based on tenant? Even simpler, why not have a different theme for each tenant, deriving from a common theme? What about widgets?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused how best to accomplish this. My controller has an action that returns one of two views specific to the tenant. One view is if the url is found in the whitelist which I have created and accessed a sitesettings part for and the other view is for when the url is not found in the whitelist. I need to keep the whitelist code on the server side so it can't be meddled with as easily and I would prefer to keep the testing of the url server side as well. That's what makes running this in the controller seem to work well for me.The problem is that the views can't be edited.

Comment: I was able to figure out a way that works. In my controller I grabbed the content item based on its TitlePart and then grabbed the text within the BodyPart. I then included it in the ViewBag and thus was able to include the text within the view.

Comment: You could have implemented `IThemeSelector` to switch the theme based on the URL.